# Dismissing a modal view and pushing to a uinavigation controller through delegation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController that has a starting view controller called: StartViewController. In this controller I launch a modal view like so:

```
// StartViewController.m
PhotoViewController *photo = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];

// Presentation
[self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the modal photo view I have two actions (UIButtons).

The first button is a Cancel button to dismiss the modal:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The second uploads a photo in which afterwards and want to go to a picture page that is in a UINavigationController with a Back button that takes you to the previous view:

```
// After photo gets saved:
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    PicsViewController *pic = [[PicsViewController alloc] init];
    [_nav pushViewController:pic animated:YES];
}];
```

In the modal view it is set as a delegate of a UINavigationController and has the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *nav;
```

But I still can't get the push to happen to the PicsViewController. Any ideas please?

Comment: You have asked basically the same question 4 times now. As suggested previously, use a delegate approach to pass the control back to the presenting view controller (don't have the presented view controller try to change the nav stack).

Comment: Yes code would help as I get the idea but having trouble still

Comment: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/delegate.html

Comment: The start controller is the delegate. The modal needs a delegate and needs to tell it when it's finished (and maybe about the image that was chosen?)

Comment: So I can't just use the UINavigationDelegate, I have to create my own protocol

Comment: So I need to make my own protocol?

Comment: You could use a callback block (instead of a protocol), but yes, using the nav delegate isn't the approach to take (you're thinking about the delegate relationship backwards I think)